# Creating a user change language script for a website

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

**UPDATE!!**

I am sorry for this post, the code I had written for this prior to posting wasnt working and I had run out of ideas, only to then have a 5 minute break and came back to it only to realise I had accidently changed the $_GET to a $_SESSION without realising and thus rendering the script useless :(

Lesson learnt? to have breaks now and again and look through my code efficiently before wasting stockoverflow's users time :)

---

---

I am looking to script into a site a language function, the site will have 3 language options; english, korean and brazilian.

I have tried building this from scratch for the past day, first using javascript/jquery/ajax with php and secondly with simple php $_GET.

I was hoping to succeed with the former attempt as I dont really want to mess about with the URL as im using mod re-write atm and cant be bothered to mess about re coding the new URL.

So what I am hoping for is some help in picking the best way in which to create a language system, remember I would rather not use  URL $_GET if at all possible.

I would also like the users choice to remain as they navigate the site using php sessions which I have tried to use but have come unstuck.

I have not placed any code in this post as atm I am looking for some tutorials or some guides on how to do this. I may add code later if there is no solution.

Thank you in advance

Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you should put this into the URL. If you select the language depending on a setting in a cookie or session data, it's very confusing, because the same URL will produce different contents, which is very bad for example when proxies cache your page or search engines index them.

The usuall way is to put the language in the path of the URL instead of a GET parameter (`http://www.example.com/en/`, `http://www.example.com/ko/`, `http://www.example.com/pt/` or `http://www.example.com/pt-BR/`).

Answer (score 1):

You can store selected language in the cookies or session. If you have any problems - don't hesitate to ask.